# Powershell, what exactly does each part of this code do?

Tags: powershell

```
    $a = gc "$home\documents\textfile.txt" 
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $a.Count + 1; $i++) 
{
    $a[($a.count-1) - $i] 
}
```

I know the first line gets the content of the text file, and the file is shown from bottom to top, but what exactly is the for loop doing step-by-step?

Comment: Close voted as 'looking for a tutorial' which is explicitly off-topic; there are lots of them already online, and not reading any, apparently not trying anything to work out what it does, but then expecting people to write you yet another a custom tutorial is a bit cheeky. Your college situation is unfortunate, but it's really for you to demand the services you paid for or a refund, rather than vent here.

Comment: Simply put its out puting the file in reverse line order.

Answer (score 2):

The for loop sets $i to 0, loops for as long as it's less than or equal to $a.Count-1 and increments after each iteration.

$a.Count is the total number of lines in the file, so $a.Count-1 is the final element (line) of $a which is an array indexed from zero.

Within each iteration $i gets larger and so the line inside the loop returns the value held at the last element minus $i.

If $a has 5 lines for example, then there are 5 elements in $a. These are $a[0] to $a[4]

On the first iteration $i is zero so the value within the square brackets evaluates to 5-1-0 = 4. This gives the last line.

On the second iteration all that changes is $i is incremented. This evaluates to 5-1-1 = 3. This is the second to last line.

This carries on until $i = 4 (which is $a.Count-1) and the code evaluates 5-1-4=0, which results in the first element of $a being output.

Hope that makes sense enough for you...

Answer (score 2):

What the for loop is doing is getting the index of the string provided by $a.

You can play with indexing by setting a variable equal to a string or array, and looking at each of the indices within it.  Take, for example, `$x = "this is a string"`.  You can then look at $x[n] where n is an integer, and it will show you what that index in the string or array contains.  For `$x[0]` Powershell would return "t", or if $x were an array of strings it would return "this".

Now that we know what indexing is, we can look at the math operators within your for loop.  To think about this in the way that Powershell is processing it, we'll work from the parenthesis out.  `$a.count` returns a value equal to the number of objects contained in $a.  If we look at what `Get-Content` returns (with help from our handy `Get-Help gc`), we can see that it is returning an object per line contained in that file.

When we apply these principles to the script you provided, we can determine that the script will return the lines of the file in reverse order.